# What is the purpose of putting multiple blanks on a microplate reader?

Tags: microbiology, spectroscopy

I am new to biology and I saw that in the software that controls the microplate reader several targets are set, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: What do you mean by "targets"? Do you mean standards - things of known quantity used to compare your sample to? Blanks usually mean a control which has a baseline reading so that you know any value above this is "positive" for your assay (statistical significance needed!) - replicates help with this.